# Image sorting/viewing software

Tags: windows, images, image-viewer, metadata-editor

I'm looking for something that can tag images, and then display any combination of tags (preferably even having the option to subtract certain tags) in a randomized slideshow.

Example: Say I have 20 pictures, 10 of them are of dogs (5 golden retrievers and 5 huskies) and 10 are of cats (5 are house cats and 5 are lions). I can appropriately tag them "dog," "lion," etc. And then view something like "dogs + house cats", or "dogs - not puppies" in a slideshow that is randomized.

Things I've tried in the past just haven't worked too well. Using Windows Explorer, since there isn't a way to tag pngs, it devolved into making many different folders turning an original count of 2000 pictures into 5000 (and it's still imperfect), and using bulk rename utility to randomize the orders. Then trying Google Photos, its facial recognition tagging is nice (I especially liked the dedicated people tab, which wouldn't be necessary, but it would be nice), if you could actually tag faces where it doesn't see any, which you can't, and there's no random slideshow feature that includes all selected pictures.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think XnView MP may be able to do what you want.  It's cross-platform software and available here: https://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/

Answer (score 0):

A lot of file tagging programs are reviewed at https://turbofuture.com/computers/Whats-the-Best-Software-for-Tagging-Files-A-Review

An app which embeds tags in the file name (such as SetTags or TagSpaces) would allow you use Windows search to look for any combination of tags. Other products offer boolean combinations of tags.

Comment: Although that seems to be a useful link, link only answers are generally frowned upon. Perhaps is you summarize the content or better yet suggest a specific program that meets the question's needs. As you gather reputation you'll get the ability to comment. This might have been better as a comment.